# can I use gsl to compute the first derivative of unknown function ( sequence of data )

Tags: c, gsl

I've downloaded the library and checked the documentation. There are three methods namely **gsl_deriv_central**, **gsl_deriv_forward**, and **gsl_deriv_backward** stated [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-Differentiation-functions.html#Numerical-Differentiation-functions). It seems that I need to define the function. In my case, the function is unknown. One of the options is using   [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). I'm looking for more efficient method to acquire the first derivative of a sequence data sampled at rate **1KHz**. Does gsl have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Another method of approximating the derivative rather than using the euler method on your data points themselved would be to fit a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) to your samples and then evaluate the derivative of the spline using the gsl function [gsl_spline_eval_deriv](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/1D-Higher_002dlevel-Interface.html#g_t1D-Higher_002dlevel-Interface).

This functionality is part of the [interpolation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation.html#Interpolation) part of GSL.